# Conditional marker matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, markers

I plot the result of a Gaussian Mixture when I have 3 type of points that are determinate by a prediction. I have a different color for each cluster predicted and now I would like to have a different marker instead of color.

```
colors=['pink' if i==0 else 'skyblue' if i==1 else 'lightgreen' for i in resultGM]
markers=['c' if i==0 else 'o' if i==1 else 'D' for i in resultGM]
ax=plt.gca()
ax.scatter(datas[:, 0], datas[:, 1], alpha=0.8, c=colors, marker=markers)   
plt.title("Calling " + name_snp)
plt.xlabel('LogRatio')
plt.ylabel('Strength')
plt.show()
```

It works perfectly for colors like this:

[image]

But I can't do the same thing with different markers, it doesn't recognize a list of markers.

How can I do to have a different marker for each cluster `(0,1,2)` like I have with colors?

Comment: You have to loop through them.  See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41078331/matplotlib-read-marker-direction-from-a-file/41078504#41078504

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line with `plt.scatter` in it to this instead:

```
for x, y, c, m in zip(datas[:,0], datas[:,1], colors, markers)
    ax.scatter(x, y, alpha=0.8, c=c,marker=m)
```

Comment: Please don't call `scatter` for each data point separately. This will make your plot unmanageable.

Comment: It's not called for each data point.  It's called for each colour in the dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `resultGM` is an array of integer labels. If it's not, turn it into one. You should have exactly one call to `scatter` for each cluster, not one call per data point as the other answer suggests:

```
colors = ['pink', 'skyblue', 'lightgreen', ...]
markers = ['c', 'o', 'D', ...]

for i in range(resultGM.max()):
    mask = (resultGM == i)
    ax.scatter(data[mask, 0], data[mask, 1], alpha=0.8, c=colors[i], marker=markers[i])
```