# How to show points in the scatter plot as plus and minus signs?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have one short question: is there any way to show the points in a scatterplot as plus and minus signs? For example, this code produces a scatter plot with blue and red points:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(25), 'y': np.random.normal(0,2500,25)})
       fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df.x, df.y, c=np.sign(df.y), cmap="bwr")
plt.show()
```

I would like have blue points as blue plus signs and red points as red minus signs. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have to mask the data and call scatter twice

Comment: Yes, a good point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add this argument to ax.scatter `marker="+"`
For a full list of markers see the [official documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/markers_api.html)

If you want conditional markers you can assign markers as an array where you run an if clause, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41099887/conditional-marker-matplotlib) previous SO thread

Comment: How do you actually propose plotting it? Are you recommending a loop with a separate call to `scatter` for each point? Because your plot will become unmanageable very quickly in that case.

Comment: It must have solved part of his problem but I agree masking is a better way IF his main concern was using multiple markers at once.

Comment: @Axblert. I've added an answer to the question you linked to. It would be nice if you posted the code you're suggesting instead of just linking to it.

Answer (score 5):

[`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html) only accepts a single [marker style](https://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers) per call, so you would have to plot each marker separately. This is fairly easy using a mask:

```
mask = df.y >= 0
ax.scatter(df.x[mask], df.y[mask], c='b', marker='+')
ax.scatter(df.x[~mask], df.y[~mask], c='r', marker='_')
```

Comment: An often seen variant uses '^' and 'v' as markers for up and down triangles

Comment: @JohanC. OP specifically asked for + and -, but I've seen that as well as a number of other options, like just red and green circles.

Comment: Yes indeed. OP can consider multiple variants and choose the best for their application.